# How to fix drag and drop Xamarin Studio?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have a problem with Xamarin Studio on windows 10 in the Design you can see it from here:

[Problem Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cOsMBN_F1I)

And please No one tells me the company recommended to use Visual Studio on Windows Okey I know it, I just want to test Xamarin in Windows I see people work in this program so I want to test it.

Comment: This is a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44359) in Xamarin Studio 6.1. The only workaround is to downgrade to Xamarin Studio 6.0.

Comment: @MattWard hey i miss you man, how can i gat 6.0?

Comment: @MattWard okey i got it i will try now

Comment: @MattWard set it as answer bro its work

Comment: @MattWard hey man i have a little problem why i am having red line?http://imgur.com/VI4NoGS